# Setting daily & weekly appointments in a given range of time in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, datetime

I am building a scheduling API with ruby on rails. Appointments are only available for a given range of time, say from April first until September first. I want to be able to make weekly and daily appointments within this range of time. Currently my create action looks like this:

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by(id: appointment_params[:user_id])
    if @user&.authenticated?(params[:token])
      @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
      # if daily, weekly here
      if @appointment.save
        render json: @appointment, status: :accepted
      else
        render json: @appointment.errors.inspect, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    else
      render json: 'Unable to Authenticate', status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

I plan on having params include something like

```
params: { appointment: {...}.
          is_weekly: true
       }
```

and then setting a new weekly appointment for the given range of weeks that appointments are available. How do I loop over ranges of weeks in ruby? Am I on the right track or am I making things to complex? Thanks !

Comment: I can't understand your goal from the question.
Please give example of the status before request, request params and then expected status after the request. Both for weekly and daily appointment. Otherwise I can't even understand what "weekly" appointment even mean.

Comment: You should take a look at the ice_cube gem. https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube